# Render different templates for ListView

Tags: python, django

I have a ListView with some good functionality that i want to use from another app. The way i did it was using `get_template_names`.

```
def get_template_names(self):
        referer = self.request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
        if "/mwo/order/" in referer:
            return ['invent/use_part.html']
        return ['invent/part_list.html']
```

Which i access from two different apps:

```
path('inventory/', PartListView.as_view(), name='partlist'),
...
path('mwo/order/<int:pk>/add_part/', PartListView.as_view(),
            name='add_part'),
```

But it causes a bug if i use a direct link to 1st url from navbar and not from another app. Now i'm new to django and i'm pretty sure there should be a better way for this. What can i use instead of request referrer to render different template for ListView when i access it from another view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `template_name` in the `.as_view`:

```
path('inventory/', PartListView.as_view(template_name='invent/part_list.html'), name='partlist'),
# …
path('mwo/order/<int:pk>/add_part/', PartListView.as_view(template_name='invent/use_part.html'), name='add_part'),
```

Then of course you should remove the `get_template_names` from the method, since otherwise you will override that behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it pays to know the framework syntax. Spent an hour on that problem yesterday).